# Program update code issue

Tags: c#, auto-update

**Hey everyone.**

I've developed a simple code to **auto-update** my program. The way it works is:

1. Program downloads a remote file that has the version string in it. If the version string is bigger than the program's, auto update initiates.
2. The program downloads the newest version of the program using a remote link with DownloadAsync.
3. The program creates a new batch file that kills the current app (The program itself), deletes the current program, and renames the new one to the application's name. Then, it runs the new updated application and deletes itself.

However, I'm facing an issue when the batch file is actually executed. Here is my code:

```
        private void WC_Completed(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
        {

        StringBuilder Batch = new StringBuilder();
        Batch.AppendLine("@echo off");
        Batch.AppendLine("taskkill /IM " + Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName + ".exe /F");
        Batch.AppendLine("ping localhost > nul");
        Batch.AppendLine("del /f " +  (char)34 + Application.ExecutablePath + (char)34);
        Batch.AppendLine("ren " + (char)34 + Application.StartupPath + @"\update.exe" + (char)34 + " " + Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName + ".exe");
        Batch.AppendLine((char)34 + Application.ExecutablePath + (char)34);
        Batch.AppendLine("del %0");

        File.WriteAllText(Application.StartupPath + @"\update.bat", Batch.ToString(), Encoding.Default);
        Process.Start(Application.StartupPath + @"\update.bat");
    }
```

For some reason, it doen't kill the current application, or it just takes too much, and the whole process is going crazy. It just runs the unupdated app because the renaming doesn't work, which causes a loop.

Can you please point out my error? I'm trying to see what's wrong!

Thank you!

Comment: I'm also wondering if it's possible to use Shell functions in C#, so I can create a shell batch run so it can actually be hidden.

Answer (score 3):

There's an easier way to update a program if it consists of one executable file:

1. Rename a running executable using [File.Move](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.move.aspx) to something like `my.exe.bak`.
2. Put an updated executable in the place of the old one.
3. Launch the new copy using `Process.Start("my.exe")` and exit the old one.
4. Upon launch test if `my.exe.bak` exists and try to delete it. You won't succeed first time, but the backup will be deleted eventually.

This way you won't need any `.bat` trickery.

You can also enchance this algorithm by passing `PID` (Process ID) of the old instance to the new one through command line arguments and then using `Process.GetProcessById(pid).WaitForExit();` to be able to delete `my.exe.bak` on the first launch and handle update process completion.

Comment: Renaming a running executable, does that work? Isn't it locked by the process?

Comment: @ulltor Is it possible to rename a running applcation?

Comment: Yes it is possible, I use that technique to update my own exe's. Move operations are allowed on running exes, often I will move the exe to a subfolder called `old` which a have my code clean up at a later date. This is *extremely* to use on terminal servers where it is hard to get a moment when everyone is logged out and you don't want to disconnect people.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain So how exactly would I approch doing that? I'm downloading the new executable using a WebClient. What name to download it as? How would I go on changing it? When to change it? Etc?

Comment: Download the file and save it as `myExe.new`, do a `File.Move(Path.Combine(pathToExe, "myExe.exe"), Path.Combine(pathToExe, "myExe.old"));` then do a `File.Move(Path.Combine(pathToExe, "myExe.new"), Path.Combine(pathToExe, "myExe.exe"));`. After you have done the exe shuffle you just start the new app and close your current one. If you are using WinForms you can just call [`Application.Restart()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.restart.aspx)